# IE8 Compatablity in iframe for ie10 page

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-10, ie8-compatibility-mode, http-equiv

We have a page written in **HTML5** running in `BrowserMode:IE10 Compatibility View` and `DocumentMode IE10`.
Inside it we have a page we host which has to be ru`n DocumentMode:IE8` or lower Otherwise the page will look bad.
I can't touch the hosted page, and i need to run mine in **IE10**(must).
Anyone has a different method of hosting the inner page other then `IFRAME`. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Nope `iFrame` is the only way to do this. You could scale the iFrame to the size of its content using one of a few different libs on GitHub if that is the issue.

Doing this would require that they are either both on the same domain or that you inject a JS file into the iFramed app.

Both of these can be done via proxying the iFrame through the server that serves the parent page.